# Matrix representation of a linear transformation in P_2

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the linear transformation T:P_2→P_2 defined by $T(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2) =a_0 + a_1(1+x)+ a_2(x+1)^2$

a)Construct the matrix representation for T when both the original space and the target space have {$1,x,x^2$} as their basis.

b)Construct the matrix representation of T when the original space has {$1,x,x^2$} as its basis, but the target space has {$1, 1+x,(1+x)^2$} as its basis.

c)Construct the representation of T when both spaces use {$1, 1+x,(1+x)^2$} as their basis.

I'm not really sure what the process of obtaining the matrix representation is at all, can someone explain it to me and help a little bit with these specific questions? I know how to get the matrix representation in the standard basis {$(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$}, but I don't know how to handle it when it involves $x$ and all that.

Also, what is the target and original space referring to?

Comment: When you have a linear transformation $T:V\to W$, $V$ is the original space and $W$ is the target space; in this case, they are the same

Comment: If $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ is a basis and $T$ is a liear operator then there are scalars $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n$ such that $T(v_1)=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots+c_nv_n$; then the column vector $(c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n)$ is the first column in the matrix representation of $T$. Similarly, $T(v_2)$ gives the second column, and so on.